# Url Rewrite with same name C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, webforms

I am trying to rewrite my url in my **Webform application** not MVC. I am using HttpModule to Perform Extension-Less URL Rewriting with IIS7.

I have a requirement to create two url like the below:

http://website.com/travel-guide - Single Url
and the sub-menu's under this:
http://website.com/travel-guide/top-10-things-to-do
so on....

But when I am using the same name it is not working, can someone guide me what is the best way to manage this?

Comment: The name of the route must be unique. Try something like: `routes.MapRoute("TravelGuide", "travel-guide", new { controller = "TravelGuide", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );` and for all others, something like: `routes.MapRoute("TravelGuide_Top10Things",
                "travel-guide/top-10-things-to-do",
                new { controller = "TravelGuide", action = "TopTenThingsToDo", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );`

Comment: FYI, I am not in MVC. I am trying this with website project and using HttpModule to Perform Extension-Less URL Rewriting with IIS7. So, if you will re-consider your reply and help me. I will be really thankful to you.

Comment: Have you tried changing the route names so that they are unique?

Comment: There is no route name option as I am not in MVC, I am doing this from web.config. For your convenience I am using the third option from this page: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net